# Non Convex Optimization update analytic proof

Tags: non-convex-optimization

I need help with the below proof,

$$A = \underset{A}{\text{argmin}}(\frac{1}{2} ||X_{(1)} - A(C \odot B)^T||^2_F + ||\Lambda \boxdot (A - \tilde{A})||_F^2 + \frac{\rho}{2} ||A - \tilde{A}||_F^2) \\ = (X_{(1)}(C \odot B) + \rho  \tilde{A} - \Lambda ) ((C \odot B)^T(C \odot B) + \rho I_R)^{-1}$$

> **Specifications**
>
> $A, \Lambda$ and $ \tilde{A} \in  \mathbb{R} ^{I \times R}$ $B \in 
>  \mathbb{R} ^{J\times R}, C \in  \mathbb{R} ^{K \times R}, $ $ X_{(1)}
>  \in  \mathbb{R} ^{I \times JK}$
>
> $A*B = trace(A^T B)$, $||A||_F^2 = trace(A^TA)$
>
> $\odot:$ Kronecker product
>
> $\boxdot:$ element wise product

[The reference of the formula page 8](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2383.pdf)

Comment: Why do you say "non convex"?

Comment: It seems that you are minimizing a quadratic functional of $A$. You only need to find the point where the derivative of this functional vanishes.

Comment: @kimchi because this is tensor factorization which is always non convex. From the same reference you would find **tensor
factorization is already a hard non-convex (multi-linear) problem**

Comment: @Gribouillis, I tried but I ended with different formula and somehow a trick is used to reach such formula with this shape, this is why I need help with it.$

Comment: Maybe the overall problem is non-convex, but you are talking about one substep of what's in the paper, and each of the terms in your expression look like convex functions of $A$ to me.

Comment: @kimchi you might be right but in the reference it is mentioned in page 13 first line solving the formula (A,B,C) = argmin(fx(A,B,C)) is non-convex. While B and C are exactly the same as A. So you might be right for A its self but for A, B and C in the whole problem is non-convex. I actually tried to get its first derivative w.r.t A and it wasn't function of A so getting its second derivative is not possible so I don't know how to confirm its convexity as well.

Comment: Your expression is a sum with positive coefficients of the function $\|\cdot\|_F$ applied arguments that are obviously linear in $A$.  A glance at  your paper shows that $\|\cdot\|_F$ is a convex function of its argument. QED.  As Gribouillis noted earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mistake copying from the paper$||\Lambda \boxdot(A - \tilde{A})||^2_F = (\Lambda * (A - \tilde{A}))$ (misunderstanding the relation between element wise product and trace)

$\dfrac{d}{dA} (\dfrac{1}{2} ||X_{(1)} - A(C \odot B)^T||_F^2) + (\Lambda * (A - \tilde{A})) + \dfrac{\rho}{2}||A - \tilde{A}||_F^2 = 0$

$= (1/2 * 2) (X_{(1)} - A(C \odot B)^T) \times -(C \odot B) + \Lambda + \rho(A-\tilde{A})$

$= -X_{(1)} (C \odot B) + A(C \odot B)^T(C \odot B)+\Lambda + \rho A - \rho \tilde{A}$

$ A ((C \odot B)^T (C \odot B) + \rho I_R) = X_{(1)} (C \odot B) - \Lambda+ \rho \tilde{A}  $

$A = (X_{(1)} (C \odot B) - \Lambda+ \rho \tilde{A})((C \odot B)^T (C \odot B) + \rho I_R)^{-1}$